# When I execute my code below, this error message occurs:

Tags: c#

`An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'in'. "

```
    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = txtfullName.Text;
        string fname = texfatherName.Text;
        string gender = "";
        bool isChecked = radioButton1Male.Checked;
        if (isChecked)
        {
            gender = radioButton1Male.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            gender = radioButton2Female.Text;
        }
        string dob = dateTimePicker1DOB.Text;
        Int64 mobile = Int64.Parse(texmobNo.Text);
        string emai = textEmail.Text;
        string semester = comboBoxSemester.Text;
        string department = comboBox2Department.Text;
        string schoo = textsch.Text;
        string duration = comboBox3Duration.Text;
        string address = richTextBoxAdress.Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "data source =CR7\\SQLEXPRESS;database =coll;integrated security =True";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert in to NewAdmission(fname,mname,gender,dob,mobile,email,semester,prog,sname,duration,addres)values('" + name + "','" + fname + "','" + gender + "','" + dob + "'," + mobile + ",'" + mobile + "','" + emai + "','" + semester + "','" + department + "','" + schoo + "','" + address + "')";

        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        DA.Fill(DS);
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved. Remembet The Registration ID", "Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
```

Comment: Better learn parameters real quick to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: `Insert in to NewAdmission` should be `Insert into NewAdmission`

Comment: remoce the space after in  "Insert into NewAdmission"

Comment: Look at the "stacktrace" of that exception, arhum. There should be a line number where it occurred. Then you have the sql command that it refers to. And in the message it tells you "somewhere near 'in' you made an ooopsie". So if you look up sql insert syntax, you fill find you made a typo. That's how you find errors in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your command text is incorrect. This line:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert in to NewAdmission(fname,mname,gender,dob,mobile,email,semester,prog,sname,duration,addres)values('" + name + "','" + fname + "','" + gender + "','" + dob + "'," + mobile + ",'" + mobile + "','" + emai + "','" + semester + "','" + department + "','" + schoo + "','" + address + "')";
```

The statement should be insert into rather than insert in to:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into NewAdmission(fname,mname,gender,dob,mobile,email,semester,prog,sname,duration,addres)values('" + name + "','" + fname + "','" + gender + "','" + dob + "'," + mobile + ",'" + mobile + "','" + emai + "','" + semester + "','" + department + "','" + schoo + "','" + address + "')";
```

You should also try to avoid passing values into the sql statement in this way as SQL injection can be a problem. Should be passed as parameters into the statement

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL syntax is `INSERT INTO` not `INSERT IN TO`